# In javascript, how to eliminate any focus in the document?

Tags: javascript

I mean, is there a way to force a blur? so if any component (button, inputext, etc.) is focused it will be blured, hope this makes sense :)

like a document.blur(), I need this because everytime user pressed F5 I need to eliminate any focus before it refreshes.

Comment: Did you try `window.blur();`?

Comment: *"I need this because everytime user pressed F5 I need to eliminate any focus"* Why in heaven's name would you need to do that?

Comment: F5 refreshes the document, what does that have to do with focus?

Comment: I need to eliminate the focuses 'before' pressing F5 sorry, with an event im displaying, misstyped

Comment: Still curious why? What is it that cares whether it has focus when you refresh?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Okay the thing is that with PrimeFaces Datatables, I found a bug, if the focus is placed on the datatables filters, and you refresh the page, something wierd is happening with ajax and rendering, so the page won't be able to refresh, but if the focus is anywhere else, or there is no focus, the page will refresh normally

Comment: I already solved by placing focus in another componente when user does F5 but I think its better to just eliminate focus

Comment: add a document event listener for click and keydown etc and set the focus to a invisible element or the window itself . Even if something got the focus. I am sure the user wont be able to do any useful with it.  event.preventDefault(); would also a idea for such listeners.

Comment: @BugsForBreakfast - Um...nothing primefaces can do will prevent user-initiated browser reload, bug or not. It could pop up an `onbeforeunload` window, but it can't *prevent* reload.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, its like a rendering problem mate, the error in the server log is "org.primefaces.expression.ComponentNotFoundException: Cannot find component for expression" But the thing is it only happens when the focus is in a datatable filter and the user refreshes, I know that it is a referencing problem but the thing is im correctly referencing it, but sometimes I do not render the component because security validations, that why I think it happens but its weird that only with the datatable filter focus lol

Comment: anyways it is solved with your answer, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `document.activeElement.blur()` but in my experience, **some** element is always going to have focus, even after you do that. For instance, on Chrome, the following ends up with `body` having focus, even after removing focus from (say) the `input`:

```js
setInterval(() => {
    if (document.activeElement) {
        document.activeElement.blur();
    }
    console.log(document.activeElement && document.activeElement.nodeName);
}, 1000);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="x">
```

But it does remove focus from the `input`, perhaps that's good enough for your use case.

---

From your comments explaining the situation further, I'd tend to think you'd want:

```
if (document.activeElement && document.activeElement !== document.body) {
    document.activeElement.blur();
}
```

Comment: Hey man this works but I have a question, the code document.activeElement && document.activeElement !== document.body doesn't work with the &&, my page crashes, I have this bug on all my javascript I can't use && operator, any idea why, im using PrimeFaces also, have you seen something like this? I had to make the 2 ifs always that I have more than 1 condition I have to make all the ifs for it to work cause I can't use && operator, I know this isn't part of question but maybe you know?

Comment: @BugsForBreakfast - If using `&&` tends to fail, it must be a primefaces thing. Perhaps you're outputting JavaScript in a context where it's expecting HTML, so it thinks the first `&` starts a character entity. A proper HTML parser would then see the next `&` and treat the resulting `&&` as text, but a broken one could be...broken. :-)

Comment: I see friend, I imagined something like that hmm, what is the solution for this behaviour? my javascript is inside the <script> tags in the xhtml

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/blur    `window.blur()` should do the trick.